# How can I add a Custom component in a Data object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-router, react-hooks

I would like sectionOne to be able to call another component but I dont seem to be getting it right. Basically below is an example of what I am trying to do. Any help would be nice. thx

```
const element = (
  <div label="go Back">
      <Home />
  </div>
);
export const appTabBarQueues = {
  sectionOne: {element},
  sectionTwo: 'Section Two',
  sectionThree: 'Section Three',
  sectionFour: 'Section Four',
  sectionFive: 'Section Five'
};
```

```
//drawer.js

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const DrawerSection = props => {
    const {sectionOne} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <div>{sectionOne}</div>
        </>
    );
};
DrawerSection.propTypes = {
    sectionOne: PropTypes.any,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Import React from 'react';


const Element = (
      <div label="go Back">
          <Home />
      </div>
    );

    export const appTabBarQueues = {
      sectionOne: <Element />,  // Capitals is important else it will be seen as html element
      sectionTwo: 'Section Two',
      sectionThree: 'Section Three',
      sectionFour: 'Section Four',
      sectionFive: 'Section Five'
    };

  or

 export const appTabBarQueues = {
      sectionOne: React.cloneElement(Element, {someProps: 'something'});
  }

  or if its not imported from elsewhere then,

  export const appTabBarQueues = {
          sectionOne: function Element(props){
            return <div label="go Back">
                      <Home />
                   </div>
          },
  }
```

With some idea based on your error message, I made some changes and could see that it works. Check below code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-field-1srdo

Comment: Hi @deechris27 thank you so much for your suggestion. your code does make sense but when i try it, it shows up as an empty div and i get the this error: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Can you paste the entire component code?  "if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render". I suppose you are using a class component. Need full code to see the context and usage.

Comment: deechris27 i was missing the drawer.js component. you can see it in the original post.

Comment: No, where is this appTabBarQueues  used? I need that component code. Are you passing appTabBarQueues  as props to DrawerSection ?

Comment: @KarinaTurtle I've added a codesanbox link to my answer with working code changes. Let me know if thats what you were looking for.

Comment: i been trying your code but it is not workin. i put my codesanbox right below your link, its not working but you can get an idea of what I am trying to do. thx

Comment: The home component or the About component don't show

Comment: I added a Home component to my existing codesandbox and was still able to render it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-field-1srdo?file=/src/App.js (updated)

Comment: @KarinaTurtle did that working example in codesandbox solve your issue? pls do accept the answer if it helped. Thanks